# When I run the code below, I am getting this error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'image, label' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

When I run the code below, I am getting this error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined.

What am I doing wrong?**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { RecipeContext } from "../context/RecipeContext";
import axios from "axios";

const Details = ({ match }) => {
const { query } = useContext(RecipeContext);
const [foodDetails, setFoodDetails] = useState({});


useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRecipes = async () => {
      await axios
        .get(
          `https://api.edamam.com/search? 
           q=${query}&app_id=${ID}&app_key=${KEY}&from=0&to=10`
        )
        .then((res) => {
          const recipe = res.data.hits.find(
            (recipe) => recipe.recipe.label === match.params.id
          );
          setFoodDetails(recipe);
          console.log(recipe);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    };
    fetchRecipes();
  }, [query]);

      return (
        <div className="container py-5">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col s12 l6">
    <p>{foodDetails.recipe.label}</p>
              <img src={foodDetails.recipe.image} alt={foodDetails.recipe.label} />

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    export default Details;


   `
```

Comment: Your axios request will not be completed before the first render, so before your data is returned and populated in `foodDetails`, its trying to access values that are only populated after the fact. Your default state is just a single empty object, so attempting to access an object within an empty object will break, as `recipe` is not defined yet.

Comment: Either change your default state to be an object more representative of the actual state, or add a conditional to check if `recipe` exists before trying to access properties on it.

Comment: I didn't have full understanding of the code until your explanation. I went for the second option and set condition to check if the object is not empty/null before accessing it and it works now.